How do I merge bottom line with previous line?
I have a pretty basic file;
15
Chapter name


some text and some more text
some text and some more text

I was trying to get something like this
Book: 15 Chapter name


some text and some more text
some text and some more text

I was trying to do this using sed with this pattern;
sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]\+\)\n\([[:alpha:]].*$\)\n$/Book: \1 \2\n/g'

Apparently this does not work from the terminal, however works perfectly inside VIM version of sed.

are the book number and chapter name always the first two lines of the file?

How can we tell in the input if 15<newline>Chapter name is the lines you want to merge or just instances of some text<newline>some text in the other blocks of text in your input? I suspect the answer lies in the way your input file is organized (which blocks appear in which order and/or with which delimiters and/or characteristics and/or keywords) but we can't tell how it's organized given just the sample input you've shown so far, Please [edit] your question to show a minimal, complete example that adequately demonstrates your needs and we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Try replacing the first line of some text and some more text in your sample input with 2024 (since 2024 is presumably a valid instance of "some text") and then executing any of the answers you have so far on that to see the problem I'm describing with your current example.

@Fravadona yeah

sed reads the input line by line, so you can't expect to match a newline-delimited string in the input.
You can however match a lone whole number, append the next line to it and work from there:
$ sed -e '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/!b' -e 'N; s/\n/ /' -e 's/^/Book: /' file
Book: 15 Chapter name


some text and some more text
some text and some more text

This skips (just outputs) all lines that aren't a whole number.  When a lone whole number is detected, however, the following line is added to the end of the buffer with N, with a delimiting newline between the two.  This newline is replaced by a space using s, and we insert the text Book:  at the start of the line.
If you know that the whole number occurs on the 1st line, you may change that initial command from /^[0-9][0-9]*$/!b to the shorter 1!b.

With Perl, in paragraph mode:
$ perl -00 -pe 's/^(\d+)\n/Book: $1 / if /^\d+/' file
Book: 15 Chapter name

some text and some more text
some text and some more text


Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne '/^ \d**1..2 $/  ??  print "Book:\t$_ "  !!  .put;'  file

Raku is a full-featured programming language in the Perl-family. Above we use the print/put idiom to combine lines. In Raku (like Perl), print does not automatically add a \n newline. Raku also has a put routine, which stands for Print-Using-Terminator which adds a \n newline terminator for you.
Once you recognize Raku's new ternary operator below, you can see how it (in combination with print/put) gives the desired answer:
Test ?? True !! False ;

Sample Input:
15
Chapter name


some text and some more text
some text and some more text

Sample Output:
Book:   15 Chapter name


some text and some more text
some text and some more text

https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#%3F_:_Ternary_operator
https://raku.org
